# How to find the usage of constant in sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search, constants

Is there a way to search through the set of (Stored Procedures, Functions, Views) for the usage of a constant?

I have a problem where I've got a sql server database.  It has quite a few stored procedures and functions declared.  I'm looking for the usage of "115", which happens to be a pay code.  I didn't write all of the code originally, so I'm looking for anywhere that a constant is declared, or the string "115" is used literally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%115%'
```

This includes constraints etc too that are omitted in sys.sql_modules and sys.procedures

Answer (score 4):

You can search [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) for `definition LIKE N'%115%'`:

```
SELECT sm.object_id, OBJECT_NAME(sm.object_id) AS object_name
  , o.type, o.type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_modules AS sm
JOIN sys.objects AS o ON sm.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE sm.definition LIKE N'%115%'
ORDER BY o.type;
```

You may get a bunch of false positives, but at least you have a starting point.

Comment: +1 slicker than my answer. Does that work in SQL Server 2000, too?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
--Option 1
SELECT DISTINCT so.name
FROM syscomments sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so ON sc.id=so.id
WHERE sc.TEXT LIKE '%Employee%'
GO
--Option 2
SELECT DISTINCT o.name ,o.xtype
FROM syscomments c
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
WHERE c.TEXT LIKE '%Employee%'
GO
```

SQL Server 2005:

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
--Searching for Empoloyee table
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%Employee%'
GO
--Searching for Empoloyee table and RateChangeDate column together
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%Employee%'
AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%RateChangeDate%'
GO
```

Both examples taken from:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/11/10/sql-server-2005-2000-search-string-in-stored-procedure/

Similarly:

http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/storedprocfinds.html

with this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Text_In_SP
@StringToSearch varchar(100) 
AS 
   SET @StringToSearch = '%' +@StringToSearch + '%'
   SELECT Distinct SO.Name
   FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
   INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
   AND SO.Type = 'P'
   AND SC.Text LIKE @stringtosearch
   ORDER BY SO.Name
GO
```

Comment: syscomments is unreliable: if your search string starts as position 3999, it won't find it because text column is nvarchar(4000).